# sfdx force:source:pull ERROR running force:source:pull: Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance

Tags: salesforcedx

sfdx force:source:pull
ERROR running force:source:pull:  Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance.

before created and opened a new scratch org

Comment: It helped me: sfdx force:source:pull -u <scratch org username/alias>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is when you create the scratch org you will need to set the default scratch org.

You can set a default username using if you have not set during scratch org creation using below

```
sfdx force:config:set --defaultusername=<username>
```

Once you set , you don't need to explicitly indicate in push or pull commands.